# What is wrong in this filterSystem function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this slider filter function with which I am trying to filter some text based on one attribute `data-length`. So that when the slider is at some value, it only shows the text with that data-length value or smaller.

this is the slider and filter function :

```
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}

 function filterSystem() {
   $("em.match.js-match").hide().filter(function () {
     var length = parseInt($(this).attr("data-length"));
     return slider.value <= length;
    }).show();
  }
```

if anyone can tell me why this function filterSystem isn't working as I want?

[here is the example](https://jsfiddle.net/jc9aqvpx/)

thank you!

p.s. I don't want to use jquery-ui

Comment: `isn't working as I want` - how should it work? What does it do instead?

Comment: but you are using jQuery in `filterSystem()`

Comment: jquery-ui !== jquery @FedeSc

Comment: wow, so all you needed to do was *actually* call the function you created! sounds legit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two problems:

1. You never called `filterSystem();`
2. You didn't include `jQuery` in your project.

Updated this:

```
slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  filterSystem();
}
```

**Working demo**

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  filterSystem();
}

function filterSystem() {
  $("em.match.js-match").css({
    'background-color': '#fff',
    'color': '#000'
  }).filter(function() {
    var length = parseInt($(this).attr("data-length"));
    if (slider.value <= length) {
      $(this).css({'background-color': $(this).attr("data-color"), 'color':'#fff'})
    }
  });

}
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Round Range Slider</h1>

<div class="" "slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>

<div class="document__body">
  <p xml:id="100">
    <em class="match js-match" data-algorithm="text" data-algorithm-type="text" data-color="#2d2f49" data-id="match_1" data-length="22" data-reference="0" style="background-color: rgb(45, 47, 73); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">This has 22 characters</em>
  </p>

  <p xml:id="101">
    <em class="match js-match match--active" data-algorithm="text" data-algorithm-type="text" data-color="#009b8b" data-id="match_20" data-length="12" data-reference="0" style="background-color: rgb(0, 155, 139); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">This only 12</em>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to ask you one more thing. I want to change instead of .hide() to remove highlighting so the background-color. Any tip on how could I achieve this?

Comment: @ga4696 I don't understand what you are asking, It's not clear to me what your asking

Comment: these two paragraphs have background-color as highlight ex: `style="background-color: rgb(0, 155, 139);` . How can I remove this "highlighting" of the text instead of hiding the text completely with .hide() . I hope I was a bit more clearer. And thank you for your help!

Comment: @ga4696 try look at the demo now

Comment: they're still disappearing and they don't have the desired background-color as before. So pretty much what I'm trying to achieve is `remove the background color to white and make the font color black` instead of hide and then get the previous background-color again when I slide below 23 `ex: value < 23`.

Comment: @ga4696 try check now